# Neither able to see Dynamic Web Project option nor able to download the update on STS

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

In the start, I was not able to see Dynamic Web Project option in my Spring Tool Suite (STS) 4. Then I tried to follow this StackOverFlow [link](https://Dynamic%20web%20project%20missing%20in%20STS) to install that option in my STS but it is not working and giving below error.

> ```
> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.31.0.v202308110616 (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 3.31.0.v202308110616)
>   Software currently installed: m2e-wtp - JSF configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.4.4.20201128-1705 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group 1.4.4.20201128-1705)
>   Software currently installed: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.28.0.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.28.0.v202211200019)
>   Software currently installed: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.28.0.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.28.0.v202211200019)
>   Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 4 4.17.2.202301310704 (org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.17.2.202301310704)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>     Web Plug-in 1.2.100.v202205260542 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web 1.2.100.v202205260542)
>     Web Plug-in 1.1.911.v201903222025 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web 1.1.911.v201903222025)
>     Web Plug-in 1.1.910.v201711032019 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web 1.1.910.v201711032019)
>     Web Plug-in 1.1.900.v201701262104 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web 1.1.900.v201701262104)
>     Web Plug-in 1.3.0.v202307260438 (org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web 1.3.0.v202307260438)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>     Eclipse IDE UI 3.20.0.v20221027-2208 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.20.0.v20221027-2208)
>     Eclipse IDE UI 3.21.100.v20230825-1346 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.21.100.v20230825-1346)
>     Eclipse IDE UI 3.17.0.v20200217-1511 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.17.0.v20200217-1511)
>     Eclipse IDE UI 3.13.0.v20170516-1223 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.13.0.v20170516-1223)
>     Eclipse IDE UI 3.13.1.v20170822-1526 (org.eclipse.ui.ide 3.13.1.v20170822-1526)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>     SSE CSS Source Editor 1.1.300.v201911262315 (org.eclipse.wst.css.ui 1.1.300.v201911262315)
>     SSE CSS Source Editor 1.2.200.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.css.ui 1.2.200.v202211200019)
>     SSE CSS Source Editor 1.0.1100.v201704250105 (org.eclipse.wst.css.ui 1.0.1100.v201704250105)
>     SSE CSS Source Editor 1.2.200.v202308160453 (org.eclipse.wst.css.ui 1.2.200.v202308160453)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>     Structured Source Editor 1.7.800.v202308200343 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.7.800.v202308200343)
>     Structured Source Editor 1.3.600.v201704250123 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.600.v201704250123)
>     Structured Source Editor 1.6.300.v202001091420 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.6.300.v202001091420)
>     Structured Source Editor 1.7.600.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.7.600.v202211200019)
>     Structured Source Editor 1.3.600.v201707042340 (org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 1.3.600.v201707042340)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>     Eclipse Web Developer Tools 1.1.601.v201602221748 (org.eclipse.wst.web.ui 1.1.601.v201602221748)
>     Eclipse Web Developer Tools 1.2.100.v201902281912 (org.eclipse.wst.web.ui 1.2.100.v201902281912)
>     Eclipse Web Developer Tools 1.2.300.v202206160209 (org.eclipse.wst.web.ui 1.2.300.v202206160209)
>     Eclipse Web Developer Tools 1.2.500.v202308160453 (org.eclipse.wst.web.ui 1.2.500.v202308160453)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools 3.10.0.v201704192341 (org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.10.0.v201704192341)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common [1.5.101.v201504022146,1.5.101.v201504022146]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools 3.10.0.v201803271721 (org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.10.0.v201803271721)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui [1.6.102.v201803271721,1.6.102.v201803271721]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools 3.10.0.v201902121810 (org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.10.0.v201902121810)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui [1.6.102.v201902121810,1.6.102.v201902121810]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools 3.10.200.v202204070252 (org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.10.200.v202204070252)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core [1.8.300.v202204070252,1.8.300.v202204070252]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools 3.13.0.v202308300413 (org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.13.0.v202308300413)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core [1.9.1.v202308300413,1.9.1.v202308300413]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.31.0.v202308110616 (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 3.31.0.v202308110616)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui 0.0.0
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 1.1.0.v202307261744 (org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui 1.1.0.v202307261744)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.21.0,4.0.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools - Common 1.5.101.v201504022146 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.common 1.5.101.v201504022146)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.0.101,1.4.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools - Core 1.8.300.v202204070252 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core 1.8.300.v202204070252)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web [1.2.0,2.0.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools - Core 1.9.1.v202308300413 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core 1.9.1.v202308300413)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web [1.2.0,2.0.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools - UI 1.6.102.v201803271721 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui 1.6.102.v201803271721)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui [1.1.0,1.3.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: JSF Tools - UI 1.6.102.v201902121810 (org.eclipse.jst.jsf.ui 1.6.102.v201902121810)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui [1.1.0,1.3.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: SSE JSP Source Editor 1.1.1200.v201702270522 (org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui 1.1.1200.v201702270522)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.3.500,1.4.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: SSE JSP Source Editor 1.1.1201.v201710051737 (org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui 1.1.1201.v201710051737)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.3.500,1.4.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: SSE JSP Source Editor 1.2.200.v201904272124 (org.eclipse.jst.jsp.ui 1.2.200.v201904272124)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.wst.css.ui [1.1.0,1.2.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: WTP Servlet UI Plug-in 1.1.910.v201701262104 (org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui 1.1.910.v201701262104)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.wst.web.ui [1.1.0,1.2.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: WTP Servlet UI Plug-in 1.1.920.v201711302141 (org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui 1.1.920.v201711302141)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.wst.web.ui [1.1.0,1.2.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: WTP Servlet UI Plug-in 1.1.921.v201903222025 (org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui 1.1.921.v201903222025)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.web [1.1.0,1.2.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: WTP Servlet UI Plug-in 1.2.0.v202307261744 (org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui 1.2.0.v202307261744)
>     To: osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui [1.1.0,2.0.0)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: m2e-wtp - JSF configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.4.4.20201128-1705 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group 1.4.4.20201128-1705)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group 3.0.0
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse Platform 4.26.0.v20221123-2302 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.26.0.v20221123-2302)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.ui.ide [3.20.0.v20221027-2208,3.20.0.v20221027-2208]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.28.0.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.28.0.v202211200019)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.css.ui [1.2.200.v202211200019,1.2.200.v202211200019]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.28.0.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.28.0.v202211200019)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.web.ui [1.2.300.v202206160209,1.2.300.v202206160209]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.28.0.v202211200019 (org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group 3.28.0.v202211200019)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui [1.7.600.v202211200019,1.7.600.v202211200019]
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>     From: Spring Tool Suite 4 4.17.2.202301310704 (org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4 4.17.2.202301310704)
>     To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.26.0.v20221123-2302,4.26.0.v20221123-2302]
> ```

So far, I have tried to install all the option from below image one-by-one but no luck. And moreover, all these options are giving almost same sort of error. Let me know if you need error from all the options.

[image: Java EE Options]

Can someone help me resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like the a conflict/incompatibility between the features you have already installed (or that come with the Spring Tools distribution in case you have used that) and the features you are trying to install. Most likely, you are trying to install versions of those features that are not compatible with the base Eclipse version that you have running inside your Spring Tools installation.

The easiest way to solve this is to start with a fresh installation of the latest Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution and then install those additional features using the pre-configured main Eclipse update site (in the `Install New Software` dialog).

If you can't do that (for whatever reason) and you have to use a specific version of the Spring Tools for Eclipse (not the latest one), you should mention the exact version that you have installed and the repository you try to install the additional features from, that might reveal additional options to get those features installed. But it could be difficult, especially if you have updated (parts of) the IDE previously.